# Получить символ по ASCII коду

Tags: java, символы

Как получить символ по его коду?

Есть таблица [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/). У меня есть значение из столбца `Oct`. Как получить символ именно по этому значению? Я пробовал варианты но там было по `Dec`.

Comment: У вас значение из `Oct` в виде строки?

Comment: строка..число.. без разницы.

Comment: Есть разница. Число не имеет системы счисления. Лишь его строковое представление.

Comment: @D-side я могу преобразовать в строку. это имею в виду.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Oct` - это восьмиричная система счисления (Octal). Используйте

```
int dec = Integer.parseInt(oct, 8);
```

для преобразования в 10-чную (это будет столбец `Dec` - Decimal), и затем используйте

```
char c = (char) dec;
```

для получения символа ASCII.

---

Полный пример:

```
String oct = "053";
int dec = Integer.parseInt(oct, 8);
System.out.println("В десятичной с.с. будет " + dec);
System.out.println("Знак ASCII будет " + (char) dec);
```

В итоге получаем в ответе `+`.

[ideone](http://ideone.com/8czRf3)